Oral Exam with Two Attempts for Each Question
For this problem I have resolved the first two parts of the exercise as follows:

For part 1, I determined that the distribution of the random variable $X$ is binomial with parameters $n = 20$ and $p = \frac{1}{k}$. Hence, $X \sim \text{Binomial}(20, \frac{1}{k})$.

For part 2, I found that the distribution of the random variable $Y$ is more complex due to the conditional nature of the second attempts. Given $X$, the number of correct answers in the first round, $Y$ is a function of a binomial distribution with parameters dependent on $X$.


Now, I need help with the third part of the exercise.
Exercise 13: Oral Exam Probability Problem
A candidate is attending an oral exam for a competition. The jury asks him 20 questions. For each question, the same number $k \geq 2$ of answers is provided, among which only one is correct. The candidate, who has not prepared for the oral exam, chooses one of the given answers at random.

Points for Correct Answers:
The jury awards one point for each correct answer. Let $X$ be the number of points obtained at the end of the oral exam. I determined that the distribution of $X$ is:
$$X \sim \text{Binomial}(20, \frac{1}{k})$$

Second Attempts for Incorrect Answers:
When the candidate gives a wrong answer, he can choose again from the remaining $k-1$ answers. The jury then awards $-1$ point for each wrong answer. Let $Y$ be the number of points obtained during these second attempts. The distribution of $Y$ depends on the initial number of correct answers $X$.

Total Points to Pass:
Let $T$ be the total number of points obtained. Determine the value of $k$ so that the candidate's average score is at least $10$ out of $20$ in order to pass.



If you want to render MathJax, enclose the TeX in dollar signs $..$.

It actually looks like you've only solved part 1; you have more to do for part 2. (It's hard to say, because you're vague about how you define $Y$ in terms of $X$, but what you really want - and what the question is looking for - is the unconditional distribution of $Y$, and there is a simple answer to this.)

I think that Y has 20-X trials, have a think about what the final distribution should be

Let $P_i$ denote the point obtained for question $i$. Hence, $T=\sum_{i=1}^{20}P_i$.
Case 1:
If $-1$ is awarded when an incorrect answer is given in each of the first and second attempts, then $P_i$ takes values $1$, $0$, and $-2$ with probabilites $\frac{1}{k}$, $\frac{k-1}{k}×\frac{1}{k-1}$, and $\frac{k-1}{k}×\frac{k-2}{k-1}$, respectively. Hence, $$\mathbb E(P_i)=\frac{1}{k}-2\frac{k-2}{k},$$ and $$\mathbb E\left (T \right)=20\left( \frac{1}{k}-2\frac{k-2}{k} \right).$$ However, only for $k\le 2$, the candidate's average score is at least 10 out of 20, which means there is no reasonable value of $k$ (i.e., $k\ge 3$) for which the candidate's average score is greater than the required minimum total point of 10 (in fact, for $k\ge 3$ the expectation becomes negative).
Case 2:
If $-1$ is awarded only when incorrect answers are given in both of the first and second attempts, then we have
$$\mathbb E\left (T \right)=20\left( \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k}-\frac{k-2}{k} \right)=20 \frac{4-k}{k}\ge 10, $$ which gives $k\le \frac{80}{30}<3$, so again we do not have any reasonable choice for $k$.
